# Split large OpenOffice file into smaller parts

Tags: openoffice-writer

I have an OpenOffice file with 2,000 pages and I need to break it into 50 parts with the same length.

How can I do that?

Comment: You want to split the document in different parts that are readable in open office or just you want to split the file in smaller parts like PDF or other formats that are created by splitting software.